# Regex to exclude specific characters

Tags: regex

I have a regex formula that I'm using to find specific patterns in my data. Specifically, it starts by looking for characters between "{}" brackets, and looks for "p. " and grabs the number after. I noticed that, in some instances, if there's not a "p. " value shortly after the brackets, it will continue to go through the next brackets and grab the number after.

For example, here is my sample data:

```
{Hello}, [1234] (Test). This is sample data used to answer a question {Hello2} [Ch.8 p. 87 gives more information about...
```

Here is my code:

```
\{(.*?)\}(.*?)p\. ([0-9]+)
```

I want it to return this only:

```
{Hello2}  [Ch.8 p. 87
```

But it returns this:

```
{Hello},  [123:456] (Test).  This is stample data used to answer a
question {Hello2}  [Ch.8 p. 87
```

Is there a way to exclude strings that contain, let's say, "{"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your pattern first matches from { till } and then matches in a non greedy way `.*?` giving up matches until it can match a `p`, dot space and 1+ digits.

It can do that because the dot can also match `{}`.

You could use negated character classes `[^{}]` to not match `{}`

```
\{[^{}]*\}[^{}]+p\. [0-9]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RvIaSu/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your expression seems to be working fine, my guess is that we wish to only capture that desired output and non-capture others, which we can do so by slight modification of your original expression:

```
(?:[\s\S]*)(\{(.*?)\}(.*?)p\. [0-9]+)
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/fmXZt9/1/)

or this expression:

```
(?:[\s\S]*)(\{.*)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/0ZwziJ/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Test

```js
const regex = /(?:[\s\S]*)(\{.*)/gm;
const str = `{Hello},  [123:456] (Test).  This is stample data used to answer a
question {Hello2}  [Ch.8 p. 87`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it in Java.  The regex should be fairly universal.

```java
      String test = "{Hello2} [Ch.8 p. 87 gives more information about..";
      String pat = "(\\{.*?\\}.*p.*?\\d+)";
      Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pat).matcher(test);
      if (m.find()) {
         System.out.println(m.group(1));
      }
```

More specific ones can be provided if more is known about your data.  For example, does each {} of information start on a separate line?  What does the data look like and what do you want to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example text, you may be able to simplify your regex a bit and avoid matching a second open curly brace before you match the page number (unless you have some other purpose for the capture groups). For example:

```
{[^{]*p\.\s\d+
```

- `{` match an open curly brace
- `[^{]*` match all following characters except for another open curly brace
- `p\.\s\d+` match "p" followed by period, space and one or more digits